# Simultaneous distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We consider two random variables X and Y with simultaneous probability distribution $p (x, y) = P (X = x ∩ Y = y)$ given by this table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x/y&  0  & 1    & 2 \\ \hline
0  & 0.1 & 0.1  & 0.2  \\ \hline
1  & 0.1 & 0.05  & 0.1  \\ \hline
2  & 0.1 & 0.15 & 0.1  \\ \hline
\end{array}
**Question:** Find the marginal probability distributions for X and Y. What is P (X = 2 | Y = 2)? Are X and Y independent random variables? Justify the answer.

To find marginal probability distributions

$p_y(0)\sum _{All\:x}\: p(x,0)=p(0.0)+p(1.0)+p(2.0)=0.1+0.1+0.1=0.3$
$p_y(1)\sum _{All\:x}\: p(x,0)=p(0.1)+p(1.1)+p(2.1)=0.1+0.05+0.15=0.3$
$p_y(2)\sum _{All\:x}\: p(x,0)=p(0.2)+p(1.2)+p(2.2)=0.2+0.1+0.1=0.4$

and do the same thing to find x. But I do not understand is what they mean by  $P\left(X=2|Y=2\right)$. And how do I know if X and Y independent random variables?

Comment: Potential typo, but $p(1,1) = 0.05$ perhaps?

Comment: @WaveX definitely, it's the only one that fits and is off by just an extra zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the definition of conditional probability.   You have already used the law of total probability to evaluate the marginal probabilities.

$$\begin{align}P(X=2\mid Y=2)&=\dfrac{P(X=2\cap Y=2)}{P(Y=2)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{p(2,2)}{p(0,2)+p(1,2)+p(2,2)}\end{align}$$

---

> And how do I know if X and Y independent random variables?

Two random variables are *defined* as independent when their joint probability function equals the product of their marginal probability functions, for *every* pair of values in their joint support.

$$X\perp Y\iff \forall x{\in}\{0,1,2\}~\forall y{\in}\{0,1,2\}~\bigl(p(x,y)=p_{\small X}(x)\cdot p_{\small Y}(y)\bigr)$$

So, does this hold?